# Ubuntu 14.10 boot takes ESC to give encryption passphrase prompt

Tags: boot, system-installation, 14.10

Need help getting a friend's Acer Aspire 5560 (2048 MB, 500 GB, Radeon graphics using 512 MB of board RAM) up and running. Crunchbang got corrupted (or hard drive had a nasty event), used UltimateBootCD tools and managed to get it running. User forgot login info. System stopped allowing boot from USB. Thought a fresh install might help.

Installed Xubuntu 14.10 from Live USB, opted for whole disk encryption option. On boot, screen went black. No response to keystrokes, except that ESC got the encryption passphrase prompt, and all is well after that for boot.

Tried the change from quiet splash to nomodeset. Worked sort of - gets to Loading initial ramdisk ... And that's it. Hitting ESC gets encryption passphrase prompt, and all is ok for rest of boot.

Is using ESC for this normal? If not, what is the fix?

Also - I did some work in unix a loooong time ago. So I need noob level instructions to fix this. Friend is short on money so open source OS is a must.

Thanks much!
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the value

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=

Within /etc/default/grub

to

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ro"

(removing the quiet and splash)

And then run:

> update-grub